# Arduino Relay Button

Tags: button, arduino, switch-statement

I am having a problem with my relay switches.  I have a 5V, four relay switch for use with an Arduino. I am trying to make it so that when I push a button, one relay goes on and then, when I press it again, the same relay goes off.

This concept works with the code when using one relay.  However, the problem is that my code works for one relay and one relay only. If I change the code and make multiple variables, it will not work.

FYI, I am using an Arduino UNO R3 ATmega 328

Keep in mind that this first code does work, but only for one relay. It works when I press the button to turn it on and then pressing the button again turns it off.

```cpp
const int rl1 = 7;
const int rl2 = 12;
const int rl3 = 2;
const int rl4 = 8;
const int button1 = 11;
const int button2 = 10;
const int button3 = 3;
const int button4 = 4;

int rl1State = LOW;
int rl2State = LOW;
int rl3State = LOW;
int rl4State = LOW;
int buttonState = LOW;
int lastButtonState = HIGH;
int reading;

long lastDebounceTime=0;
long debounceDelay = 50;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(rl1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(button4, INPUT);

}

void loop() {

  reading = digitalRead(button1);


  if(reading != lastButtonState){
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
    lastButtonState = reading;
  }

  if((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay){
    if(buttonState != lastButtonState){
      buttonState = lastButtonState;
      if(buttonState == HIGH){
        rl1State = !rl1State;
        digitalWrite(rl1, rl1State);


      }
    }
  }



}
```

I tried this code for multiple relays:

```cpp
const int rl1 = 7;
const int rl2 = 12;
const int rl3 = 2;
const int rl4 = 8;
const int button1 = 11;
const int button2 = 10;
const int button3 = 3;
const int button4 = 4;

int rl1State = LOW;
int rl2State = LOW;
int rl3State = LOW;
int rl4State = LOW;


//States
int buttonState1 = LOW;
int lastButtonState1 = HIGH;
int buttonState2 = LOW;
int lastButtonState2 = HIGH;
int buttonState3 = LOW;
int lastButtonState3 = HIGH;
int buttonState4 = LOW;
int lastButtonState4 = HIGH;

//Read State

int reading1;
int reading2;
int reading3;
int reading4;

long lastDebounceTime1=0;
long debounceDelay1 = 50;

long lastDebounceTime2=0;
long debounceDelay2 = 50;

long lastDebounceTime3=0;
long debounceDelay3= 50;

long lastDebounceTime4=0;
long debounceDelay4 = 50;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(rl1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(button4, INPUT);

}

void loop() {

  reading1 = digitalRead(button1);
  reading2 = digitalRead(button2);
  reading3 = digitalRead(button3);
  reading4 = digitalRead(button4);


//Relay 1
  if(reading1 != lastButtonState1){
    lastDebounceTime1 = millis();
    lastButtonState1 = reading1;
  }
    if(reading1 != lastButtonState1){
    lastDebounceTime1 = millis();
    lastButtonState1 = reading1;
  }
  if((millis() - lastDebounceTime1) > debounceDelay1){
    if(buttonState1 != lastButtonState1){
      buttonState1 = lastButtonState1;
      if(buttonState1 == HIGH){
        rl1State = !rl1State;
        digitalWrite(rl1, rl1State);


      }
    }
  }


  //Relay 2
  if(reading2 != lastButtonState2){
    lastDebounceTime2 = millis();
    lastButtonState2 = reading2;
  }

  if((millis() - lastDebounceTime2) > debounceDelay2){
    if(buttonState2 != lastButtonState2){
      buttonState2 = lastButtonState2;
      if(buttonState2 == HIGH){
        rl2State = !rl2State;
        digitalWrite(rl2, rl2State);


      }
    }
  }



}
```

I also tried to re-make all the variables for each button and relay, but it still does not work.

On another note, one of my relays does not work when put to any pin (when all the pins are connected) but it works only when one of the pins are disconnected. It's really weird. I tested the relay and it's fine and I changed the Arduino but still have the same issue.

Comment: I assume the Buttons/Input Pins connected to ground when not pressed, right? Did you Connect then all on one ground Channel? Maybe when you press one Button ground is not low anymore, because current is flowing and so the pins could get recognized as HIGH by the Arduino.

Comment: The buttons are connected to the same ground all of them. The first button works like a charm, actually perfectly and it's very reactive, the other ones do not respond at all. Sorry for the delayed answer I had a summer class exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH! This will work here is the code and the schematics for all of you that have this problem (saw on the internet a lot do have this problem), as well THANK YOU ALL for you help in solving this matter! ENJOY!

[Circuit (Please note the relay cluster I am using was not available on Fritzing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGWDL.jpg)

Code:

```
//Buttons

int button1 = 7;
int button2 = 6;
int button3 = 4;
int button4 = 2;


//Relays
int rl1 = 13;
int rl2 = 12;
int rl3 = 11;
int rl4 = 8;


//States for Relay and Button (1)

int state1 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading1;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous1 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

//States for Relay and Button (2)

int state2 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading2;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous2 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

//States for Relay and Button (3)

int state3 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading3;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous3 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin

//States for Relay and Button (4)

int state4 = HIGH;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading4;           // the current reading from the input pin
int previous4 = LOW;    // the previous reading from the input pin




// the follow variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long time1 = 0;          // the last time the output pin was toggled
long time2 = 0;
long time3 = 0;
long time4 = 0;

long debounce1 = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers
long debounce2 = 200;
long debounce3 = 200;
long debounce4 = 200;


void setup()
{
  pinMode(button1, INPUT);
  pinMode(button2, INPUT);
  pinMode(button3, INPUT);
  pinMode(button4, INPUT);

  pinMode(rl1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(rl4, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {

  reading1 = digitalRead(button1);
  reading2 = digitalRead(button2);
  reading3 = digitalRead(button3);
  reading4 = digitalRead(button4);


  // if the input just went from LOW and HIGH and we've waited long enough
  // to ignore any noise on the circuit, toggle the output pin and remember
  // the time
  //Condition Relay 1
  if (reading1 == HIGH && previous1 == LOW && millis() - time1 > debounce1) {
    if (state1 == HIGH)
      state1 = LOW;
    else
      state1 = HIGH;

    time1 = millis();    
  }

  //Condition Relay 2
    if (reading2 == HIGH && previous2 == LOW && millis() - time2 > debounce2) {
    if (state2 == HIGH)
      state2 = LOW;
    else
      state2 = HIGH;

    time2 = millis();    
  }

  //Condition Relay 3
    if (reading3 == HIGH && previous3 == LOW && millis() - time3 > debounce3) {
    if (state3 == HIGH)
      state3 = LOW;
    else
      state3 = HIGH;

    time3 = millis();    
  }

  //Condition Relay 4
    if (reading4 == HIGH && previous4 == LOW && millis() - time4 > debounce4) {
    if (state4 == HIGH)
      state4 = LOW;
    else
      state4 = HIGH;

    time4 = millis();    
  }




  digitalWrite(rl1, state1);
  digitalWrite(rl2, state2);
  digitalWrite(rl3, state3);
  digitalWrite(rl4, state4);


  previous1 = reading1;
  previous2 = reading2;
  previous3 = reading3;
  previous4 = reading4;
}
```